# MongoDate toDateTime() function is not defined?

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime

This is stumping me... I'm using the exact example from:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodate.todatetime.php

but I'm getting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MongoDate::toDateTime()

```
<?php
$d = new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-11-18 11:01:25"));
var_dump($d);
var_dump( $d->toDateTime() );
?>
```

The exact output I get is:

```
object(MongoDate)#1 (2) {
  ["sec"]=>
  int(1416330085)
  ["usec"]=>
  int(0)
}
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MongoDate::toDateTime() in /xxx/testmongodate.php on line 5
```

PHP version:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

PHP config:

```
$ php -i | grep mongo
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongo.ini,
mongo
mongo.allow_empty_keys => 0 => 0
mongo.chunk_size => 262144 => 262144
mongo.cmd => $ => $
mongo.default_host => localhost => localhost
mongo.default_port => 27017 => 27017
mongo.is_master_interval => 15 => 15
mongo.long_as_object => 0 => 0
mongo.native_long => 0 => 0
mongo.ping_interval => 5 => 5
```

I have been successfully using this installation to insert into and read from an actual mongo database, but now I'm trying to work with MongoDate objects as they are read out of mongo, trying to format them for insert into another database... that is why I'm looking to use this method... but it doesn't seem to be found... ??

```
$ uname -a
Linux server1 3.13.0-52-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 4 04:32:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How's your PECL version? `PECL mongo >= 1.6.0`

Comment: not exactly sure how to check, but did this: $ pecl version
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0
Running on: Linux server1 3.13.0-52-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 4 04:32:59 UTC 2015 x86_64

Comment: `pecl list` should be the command to list installed packages and their versions. if it returns an older version than 1.6.0 then my assumption would be the installed package simply lacks that functionality.

Comment: ` $ pecl list
  Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
  =========================================
  Package Version State
  oci8    2.0.8   stable`

Comment: looks like it was not installed through pecl, I'll check with the sysadmin to see how it was installed...

Comment: You might be able to check what is available via a `phpinfo()` call

Comment: Yes, that's what I have in my original question where I show the output of php -i | grep mongo

Comment: @Wes the `php -i | grep mongo` does actually not show the version - but you should see it when using e.g. `php -i | grep -5 mongo` which shows a bit more context. Beside that I've experienced the same issue as you but in my case it happened because I ran some Codeception tests locally and not inside my Vagrant container - where the latter had 1.6.10 installed as expected it was 1.5.7 for the local environment.

Comment: Note: MongoDate->toDateTime is only supported for PHP 5.3.4 and later

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming to this question late (as I did), the likely issue is that the PHP is using a different Mongo driver. There are currently 2 and the below code is for the legacy driver.
The solution with the legacy driver is to get the date from the Mongo Date using the PHP date function:

```
<?php 
$d = new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-11-18 11:01:25"));
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:m:s',$d->sec);
var_dump( $newdate );
?>
```